# Strange thread behaviour

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm relatively new to python but not to multi-threaded software so I can't explain a particular behaviour that I'm seeing. My program is quite simple: I monitor the output of the linux command 'iostat' and do something in some situation. My code is as follows:

```
class SysMonitor(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.isStopping = False
    self.ioprocess = []

def run(self):
    self.ioprocess = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/iostat', '-p', 'sda', '60'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p = self.ioprocess
    i = 0

    # Discard first output
    while (i < 11):
        p.stdout.readline()
        i = i + 1

    # Now keep on waiting on new output from iostat and then process it when it comes in
    while (not self.isStopping):
        select.select([p.stdout], [], [])

        # Don't process the last output if we are stopping
        if (self.isStopping):
            print 'Quitting, discarding last buffer:' + str(self.isStopping)
            continue

        # do some p.stdout.readline() and process the data

def stop(self):
    self.isStopping = True
    self.ioprocess.terminate()
```

What I don't understand is that when I call the 'stop' function, the program sometimes crashes because the select is freed because EOF is written in the stdout buffer, but isStopping is still False. How can this happen?

Answer (score 2):

If `stop()` is called outside the thread, it could lead to random issues yes. Because when you'll call stop(), the thread can be anyway, in a print, or a select etc.

Just move the your `terminate()` at the end of the `run()` method. Then setting the `isStopping` to True will correctly leave the loop, and then, terminate the process.

If you want to wait for it, you can join the thread with:

```
def stop(self):
    self.isStopping = True
    self.join()
```

Comment: The problem with putting the terminate in run() is that program will not terminate immediately when requested because it may be stuck on the select.select call. So in this case I could be stuck waiting for up to 1 minute for the program to terminate.

Comment: Then you can use timeout option in select, or send a signal (`import os, signal; os.kill(0, signal.SIGPIPE)`) before the `self.join()`. The documentation of select show that if a signal is received, the select() will timeout at the signal reception

Comment: This sounds good, but it doesn't work. I've changed my code as follows:
`ready, _, _ = select.select([p.stdout], [], []); if (self.isStopping or (not ready)): continue` and in the stop(self) function I have `self.isStopping = True; os.kill(0, signal.SIGPIPE); self.join()`

The signal reaches the select but the `ready` variable is always a file descriptor: _[<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0xb2ce40>]_ so I run into the same problem. Since the signal makes the select timeout, shouldn't `ready` be an empty list? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can't you just make a test for break after the select ? (and then not take care of the ready variable ?)

Comment: What do you mean by test for break?

Answer (score 2):

Building on [tito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8763471/190597), and regarding your comment, you could use a timeout in `select.select`:

```
    while (not self.isStopping):
        ready, _, _ = select.select([p.stdout], [], [], 5.0)

        # Don't process the last output if we are stopping
        if (self.isStopping):
            print 'Quitting, discarding last buffer:' + str(self.isStopping)
            continue
        if ready:
            # do some p.stdout.readline() and process the data

    self.ioprocess.terminate()
```

Above, the timeout is 5.0 seconds. I figure that is long enough not to hammer the system and short enough for a reasonable termination. Change to fit your taste.

Comment: This will work but I feel that it's only a work around from the real problem: i.e. that isStopping flag doesn't get transmitted to the thread before the process is terminated and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to end the thread when the application ends then set the thread as a daemon.